# How do I create an unsigned integer array of size 128 bits in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I can use `Uint8Array` for 8 bits, `Uint32Array` for 32 bits, but I can't find an alternative which allows me to use 128 bits.  Is there a computationally and memory efficient way to store such values?

At the moment I'm just approximating it by using an `Array`, but that appears to be ~5x slower than a `Uint32Array`.

Comment: how about `Uint32Array` with 4 elements per 128 bit item, similar to how it is done for `ImageData.data` rgba color values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Typed arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays) only go as large as `Float64Array`. If you need `uint`s, the largest you can get is `UInt32Array`. If you need 128 bits, you'll need to create logic which can place your bits into a `UInt32Array` as 4 DWORDs.

Also keep in mind that [JavaScript Bitwise Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) only operate at 32-bit, so even if you try to shift the DWORDs of your values to re-assemble your 128-bit number, it will likely truncate your data into nothing.